# How to prevent overflowing flexbox without giving explicit sizes

Tags: html, css, svg, flexbox

At a certain browser size ratio, [this codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VLbzqL) looks like the image below.  At wider browser widths, the svg (vertical green lines with text "Top" and "Bottom") on the right overflows its flexbox off the top and bottom.  I've tried various permutations of width/height: auto/100%/min-content on the various flex items, but don't seem to have hit on the *magic* combination.  Additionally, even using codepen's *Autoprefixer*, the browsers all interpret this differently (IE makes the SVG too small and doesn't expand it, Firefox pushes the Header and Footer off the page, and Chrome just overflows it).

Ideally, the outcome I would *like* to have is:

- the svg image to be as large as possible, while maintain its aspect ratio, and not overflowing into other content.
- the three little divs (tables) on the left to flow vertically, except if there is not enough room, and then to start flowing horizontally and *pushing* the svg over (effectively making it smaller). (this goal is less important)

I've tried to grok the [flexbox layout algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/2015/WD-css-flexbox-1-20150514/#layout-algorithm), but failed miserably when one of the first things one needs to know is if it has a [definite](http://www.w3.org/TR/2015/WD-css-flexbox-1-20150514/#definite) size, and the definition of that is recursive by referring & linking to `definite` throughout:

> If a percentage is going to be resolved against a flex item’s main size, and the flex item has a definite flex basis, and the flex container has a definite main size, the flex item’s main size must be treated as definite for the purpose of resolving the percentage, and the percentage must resolve against the flexed main size of the flex item (that is, after the layout algorithm below has been completed for the flex item’s flex container, and the flex item has acquired its final size).

I've gone through both the [guide to flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), and the [flexbox in 5 minutes](http://flexboxin5.com/) tutorials, but their examples are relatively basic (and I realize I'm likely just missing something very basic for my issue).  **If anyone can point to resources with a more in-depth treatment of nested items in flexboxes, that would be appreciated (especially treatment when items aren't given explicit sizes)**.

[image: Desired look]

**HTML:**

```
<div id="header">
  <div>Header</div>
</div>
<div id="main">
  <div id="first_col">

    <div class="wrapper">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Col 1</th>
            <th>Col 2</th>
            <th>Col 3</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>some</td>
            <td>content</td>
            <td>here</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>some</td>
            <td>content</td>
            <td>here</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

    <div class="wrapper">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Col 1</th>
            <th>Col 2</th>
            <th>Col 3</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>some</td>
            <td>content</td>
            <td>here</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>some</td>
            <td>content</td>
            <td>here</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

    <div class="wrapper">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Col 1</th>
            <th>Col 2</th>
            <th>Col 3</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>some</td>
            <td>content</td>
            <td>here</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>some</td>
            <td>content</td>
            <td>here</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div id="second_col">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1800 1800" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
      <defs>

        <rect id="dummy_content" height="1740" width="30" rx="5" ry="5" style="fill:green; stroke-width:2; stroke:#696969" />

      </defs>
      <use xlink:href="#dummy_content" x="168" y="30" />
      <use xlink:href="#dummy_content" x="576" y="30" />
      <use xlink:href="#dummy_content" x="984" y="30" />
      <use xlink:href="#dummy_content" x="1392" y="30" />
      <text font-size="100" fill="red" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" x="900" y="100">Top</text>
      <text font-size="100" fill="red" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" x="900" y="1700">Bottom</text>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">Footer</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#header,
#main,
#footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid green;
}

#header {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  height: 3rem;
}

#main {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

#footer {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  height: 3rem;
}

svg {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#first_col,
#second_col {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}

#first_col {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

#second_col {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 1rem;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to somehow fulfil the first part of your question:

<kbd>[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpmXVx)</kbd>

The key to contain the SVG is resetting its behaviour with `position: absolute` and adding `align-self: stretch;` to its parent, so the SVG has the maximum size information of its parent as a basis.

As of the second part, I'm not sure what you want to achieve. The layout can't switch freely between row and columns, except with fixed breakpoints.

Comment: Thanks for the effort.  `align-self` is generally an over-ride for one particular item (out of a group).  In this case there is only one item, so one shouldn't over-ride, you can just change the parent (`#main`) to `align-items: stretch;`.  Changing just that on your codepen ([update here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqjMQw)) also gets the first column to wrap when the height is too short.  (So this updated layout does basically the same as mine, but without height calc part)

Comment: My issue is totally irrelevant to the OP, but take your +1 for `align-self: stretch;`. Lol.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did manage to more-or-less solve my issue:

Adding:

- display: flex;
- height: 100%;

to `#main`, and:

- height: calc(100% - 6rem -2px);

to `#second_col`

and removing:

- align-items: center;

from `#main`

got the svg to grow or expand within its div depending on the browser height, and allowed the first column to wrap into a row if the height is too small.

Updated codepen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJPVYV).

This still isn't exactly what I want (I'd really like the first column to *push* the second column over when it switches to row-based).